# iterate throught Dataframe and get the indexes

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I would like to iterate throught the DataFrame ows/column, get the current row/column index and perform some other operations. Is there any handy method to get the index number from Row/Column?

The goal is to save an output to the xlsx file by the Apache POI library, so it's required to iterate for each cell, probably.

```
// proceed throught each row/column of the DataFrame
myDataframe.foreach{row =>
  row.toSeq.foreach{col =>
    val rowNum = row.???
    val colNum = col.???
    // further operations on the data...
    // like save the output to the xlsx file with the Apache POI
  }
}
```

I'm working on Spark 1.6.3. and Scala 2.10.5.

Comment: A **DataFrame** is a _distributed collection_ by nature. And an **Excel file** is a _local file_ by nature. If you are sure the data is small enough to be written on a single file, just `collect()` it, and process the results with normal Scala / Java code.

Comment: I concur with @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez If it fits in an excel file, it should fit in memory, thus you can collect and process it. `foreach` is usually use for side-effects and this is not what you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add index using **row_number()** :

```
  val myDataframe = sc.parallelize(List("a", "b", "c", "d")).toDF("value")
  val withIndex = myDataframe.select(row_number().over(Window.orderBy('value)).as("index").cast("INT"), '*)

  myDataframe.foreach { row =>
    for (i <- 0 until (row.length)) {
      val rowNum = row.getInt(0)
      val colNum = i
    }
  }
```

But if you want to save df to excel file you should collect your data.
Then convert it to Array of arrays / 2d array.

```
 val list: Array[Array[String]] = withIndex
    .select(concat_ws(",", withIndex.columns.map(withIndex(_)): _*))
    .map(s => s.getString(0))
    .collect()
    .map(s => s.toString.split(","))

  for (elem <- 0 until  list.length) {
    for (elem2 <- 0 until list.apply(elem).length) {
      println(list.apply(elem).apply(elem2),", row:"+elem+", col:"+elem2)
    }
  }

(1,, row:0, col:0)
(a,, row:0, col:1)
(2,, row:1, col:0)
(b,, row:1, col:1)
(3,, row:2, col:0)
(c,, row:2, col:1)
(4,, row:3, col:0)
(d,, row:3, col:1)
```

I don't know how apache poi works in scala but in java it should looks like this:

```
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
            Sheet newSheet = workbook.createSheet("spark");

            // your data from DataFrame
            Object[][] bookComments = {
                    {"1", "a"},
                    {"2", "b"},
                    {"3", "c"},
                    {"4", "d"},
            };

            int rowCount = 0;

            for (Object[] aBook : bookComments) {
                Row row = newSheet.createRow(++rowCount);

                int columnCount = 0;

                for (Object field : aBook) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                    if (field instanceof String) {
                        cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                    } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                        cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                    }
                }

            }

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("JavaBooks.xlsx");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
            outputStream.close();
```